# no error message but all of data fail to import

Tags: php, codeigniter, importerror

i want to import data from an excel file to phpmyadmin. i use library excel_reader2. when i click the import button there is no error message but all data fail to import.

here is my code

```
<?php

include "excel_reader2.php";

mysql_connect("dbHost", "dbUser", "dbPass");
mysql_select_db("dbname");

$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']);

$baris = $data->rowcount($sheet_index=0);

$success = 0;
$fail = 0;

for ($i=2; $i<=$row; $i++)
{
$id = $id->val($i, 1);
$name = $name->val($i, 2);
$address = $address->val($i, 3);

$query = "INSERT INTO student VALUES ('$id', '$name', '$address')";
$result = mysql_query($query);

 if ($result) $success++;
 else $fail++;
}

echo "<h3>Import data finished</h3>";
echo "<p>Sum of success data : ".$success."<br>";
echo "Sum of fail data : ".$fail."</p>";
?>
```

and here is the result in my browser

Import data finished
Sum of success data : 0
Sum of fail data : 100

Please, somebody help me.. Big thanks..

Comment: Please try some basic debugging.  Put echo statements in to print out insert statements to see what's being executed.  print out the database error using mysql_error($query) and research using PDO for your database access then we can look at helping you.

Comment: From Mihai @Mihai: Is the table student made up of only 3 columns?Is the column ID autoincrement?

Comment: sorry @TobyAllen i don't understand what you mean, can you just give me the step?

Comment: @Mihai it's just an example, my real program about 10 columns. the id is serial, is't the problem?

Comment: Find the error you are getting from mysql_error please try to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe are you wrong when you get your datas from the excel. You may try that:

```
$id = $data->val($i, 1);
$name = $data->val($i, 2);
$address = $data->val($i, 3);
```

You start from i=2 and var baris is never used

Comment: still result in my browser like that (my post)..
i start from 2 because the 1 is column name in excel file

Comment: I was talking about replacing the occurence of `$id->` by `$data->` as you are getting the result from the $data, the id (and name and adress) certainly don't have val function as they certainly are strings...

Comment: `$row` isn't even initialised before the loop!